# how to navigate report to jsp through hyperlink in report

Tags: birt

i am very new  birt tool,

my question is

how to navigate from report to jsp through hyperlink in report

Advanced Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By using hyperlink options you can access your application JSP page

STEPS: hyperlink-->select URI radio button there you can pass your parameter/method name of your class

Good Luck